# Optimizing JQuery Datatables - working with large dataset while taking more than 30 minutes for processing in the middle layer (JAVA)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, datatables

My application takes in input parameters from UI and executes a set of SQL queries that would return data for the jquery datatables. Each row in the datatables requires processing of multiple sql queries based on the input parameters. So when the input parameters are fed in to retrieve rows more than 1000, you could imagine the processing time it would take. So i am just wondering if we could program it in such a way that as and when a row is processed, could it be returned to the UI while the middle layer continues to work on processing other rows? I'm using JQuery, Ajax to send the input parameters to a servlet which calls the java class to process these rows and sends back the JSON array of data. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTables [server side processing](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) option.

> ...and if you are working with seriously large databases, you might
>   want to consider using the server-side options that DataTables
>   provides. Basically all of the paging, filtering, sorting etc that
>   DataTables does can be handed off to a server (or any other data
>   source - Google Gears or Adobe Air for example!) and DataTables is
>   just an events and display module.

It will fetch only few records and will display it to the user, rest of the records are only fetched when required like when user clicks on next/previous,

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code snippet? Once the data is returned to the UI, how will rest of the records be fetched?

Comment: @user2520416: Basically it fetches the first 10 results and fetches the next 10 when user clicks on next and so on. Records start and index is sent to server when user clicks on next and you need to use it in query and return the desired result.Go through the mentioned link. It contains the  details and code snippet.

Comment: Its not a straight sql fetch. Based on the input parameter, once i fetch the data from the DB and then process it and create Objects and then convert it to JSON Object. Creating one row worth of data requires atleast 4 sql fetch queries and then processing the fetched data to create a row's worth of data. So i'm still not sure how the server-side processing will help me in this case.

Comment: @user2520416: using start and end index you are restricting your SQL to very few records. Fetching 10 records will be more efficient then fetching data that is taking 30 minutes. Also you should recheck your design as 30 minutes is way far than the average one

Answer (score 0):

Rule one of database programming is to do everything possible at the server, rather than shipping data to the application to be processed there and shipped back. Try to express your entire application as a set of SQL statements only.